# Is there a plugin for image gallery per category in WordPress?

Tags: image, wordpress, gallery

I am looking for a plugin that can allow me to manage image gallery per category in WordPress. All the posts in a particular category should have the same set of images or a single featured image (as defined in the CMS).

Quick help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this article will help you to find some existing plugin: http://speckyboy.com/2010/06/30/top-10-content-slider-plugins-for-wordpress/

I've customized wp-featured-content-slider in my [agency blog](http://blog.mba-multimedia.org/) to show only some categories in the slider, but it's not a plugin parameter you can configure in the admin section.

In your theme, you'll have to combine tests like :

```
if (is_category('XXX'))...
```

and

```
query_posts( 'cat=XXX' )
```

before the loop to only query the posts of the current category (see [query_post codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)).

Hope this will help you!